# REST HttpWebResponse not returning xml data as string

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rest, webforms

Firstly, I understand this code isn't necessarily "safe" and is VERY basic. I'm learning how to consume rest services with web forms in C# (both are new topics for me). Pretty much the only thing there is 2 textboxes for authentication credentials, a query textbox and button to send the request with a label. I just want to enter the ID1 into the textbox, and then return the First and Last name for the entry with that ID.

I have tried many different ways after thoroughly searching the web but can't seem to figure out the issue.

**The Issue:**  *The StreamReader data from the WebResponse isn't coming back as XML.*

**The Question:** *How do I return the XML tags that I want? Do I need to parse them? If so, how?*

The XDoc version is returning nothing while the straight stream reader is returning a string with some data in addition to numbers that shouldn't be there and no angle brackets. Below is the code as it stands now:

```
if (QueryTextBox2.Text != "")
        {
            string tableName = "Entry";
            string requestURL = "https://myUrl.com/rest/services/" + tableName;
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding:='charset=utf-8'";
            request.Headers["CustomUserName"] = TextBox1.Text;
            request.Headers["CustomPassword"] = TextBox3.Text;

            string xml = "<Entry><ID1>" + QueryTextBox2.Text + "</ID1></Entry>";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.ToString());
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) { 

                Stream postData = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(postData, Encoding.UTF8);
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Label2.Text = result;

            } else
            {
                Label2.Text = "There was an error: " + response.StatusDescription;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox2.Text = "Please Enter an ID";
        }

    }
}
```

I have also tried using:

```
                XDocument doc = new XDocument();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    doc = XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    string fname = doc.Root.Element("NameFirst").Value;
                    string lname = doc.Root.Element("NameLast").Value;
                    Label2.Text = fname + lname;
```

to replace the whole block within: if statusCode == OK.

The data returned from the firefox Poster add-on is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title type="text">Search Results</title>
<id>https://myUrl.com/rest/services</id>
<updated>2015-10-07T09:51:32Z</updated>
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://myUrl.com/rest/services" />
<entry>
<id>https://myUrl.com/rest/services</id>
<Entry>
<ID1>900009</ID1>
<NameLast>Smith</NameLast>
    <NameFirst>Tom</NameFirst>
    <NameTitle></NameTitle>
    <NamePreferred>Alex</NamePreferred>
    <NameWeb>tsmith</NameWeb>
    <NameOther></NameOther>
    <NameInitials></NameInitials>
</Entry></content></entry></feed>
```

I've removed a lot of the response data because it's so large and anonymized it all for the most part so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use System.Net.Http.HttpClient, it has a much easier interface for consuming http requests.

I haven't tested the document parsing, but just follow the nested levels in until you find the element you want.

```
async void Main()
{
    var textBox2String = "2"

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2String))
    {
        const string table = "Entry";

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var url = $"https://myurl.com/rest/services/{table}";
        var xml = $"<Entry><ID1>{textBox2String}</ID1></Entry>";

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("CustomUserName", "username");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("CustomPassword", "password");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"));
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var document = XDocument.Parse(content);
            var entry = document.Root.Element(table);
            var firstName = entry.Element("FirstName").Value;
            var lastName = entry.Element("LastName").Value;

            $"{firstName} {lastName}".Dump();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred processing this request: {content}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        textBox2String = "Please enter an ID";
    }
}
```